# parsing file with spring batch ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my spring batch application I have configured a `FlatFileItemReader` as follows:

```
public PositionRowReader() {

    reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setLinesToSkip(1); //skip header row

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";");
    tokenizer.setStrict(false);
    tokenizer.setNames(PosFieldSetMapper.COLUMN_NAMES);

    DefaultLineMapper<PosRow> posLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    posLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    posLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PosFieldSetMapper());
    posLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();


    reader.setLineMapper(posLineMapper);
```

}

In my `file` which I am reading, I can have data which I do not wish to process and want to ignore for example:

```
20180123;ABC;00001;  
20180123;ABC;00001;
;;;
;;;
```

I want to ignore lines with ;;;, in other words they are just empty. Is there a way I can do this? I have a `FieldSetMapper` also.

Currently I am gettings exceptions for example:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2253 in resource=[file [...]], input=[;;;;;;;;]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip lines with ItemReader in Spring-Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228809/how-to-skip-lines-with-itemreader-in-spring-batch)

Answer (score 0):

I checked for empty on FieldSetMapper:

```
if (!fieldSet.readString("client").isEmpty()) {
        pos.setSedol(fieldSet.readString("client"));
    }
```

Then on ItemProcessor process() method I check for Null in values:

```
  if (!line.isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
```